# TextInputLayout line color not changing for API > 22 Programatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, line, android-textinputlayout

The piece of code is as follows

```
TextInputEditText textInputEditText;
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(textInputEditText, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)}));
```

When the edittext is focused line color changes to **colorAccent**. I want to retain **holo_red_dark** when edittext is focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily via XML

1.create a new Theme

```
<style name="MyTextInputEditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/holo_red_dark</item>
  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/holo_red_dark</item>
  <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>
```

2.Apply that theme on xml

```
<TextInputEditText
  .
  .
  android:theme="@style/MyTextInputEditTextTheme">

</TextInputEditText>
```